# Dynamically add a css class to cytoscape node on the tap of the node using cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape, cytoscape-web

I am trying to add class on the tap of the node in cytoscape.js. Here is the link for the complete code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kpnys1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

ngViewAfterInit function

```
  cy.on("tap", "node", function(evt) {
      var node = evt.target;
      console.log("tapped " + node.id());
      cy.nodes(node).classes("foo");
    });
```

Tap works fine but it does not add any class to the node. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to use the correct method for that. Currently, your code calls `node.classes()`, which deletes all previous classes of the node (you basically overwrite the classes array of a node).

What you want to do: Use `node.addClass("foo")` and add an entry in your stylesheet:

```
{
    selector: ".foo",
    css: {
        "background-color": "green"
    }
}
```

The dot indicates a class, but you can specify even further. If you want to add the foo class only to parent nodes, change `.foo` to `:parent.foo`.

But aside that, your code acutally worked (kind of), the class was present when clicking on a node. Here is the edited version of your stackblitz, I added the mentioned changes and gave one parent element the class "bar". If you click on a parent, the node will change the background-color to green and log its current classes to the console:

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nql5dd?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Is there a way to disable scroll zooming? If I have a long chart and there is a scroll bar, the mouse wheel just zooms the chart. Can I disable that?

Comment: Just use the `userZoomingEnabled: false,` in your cytoscape.js init. userZoomingEnabled : Whether user events (e.g. mouse wheel, pinch-to-zoom) are allowed to zoom the graph. Programmatic changes to zoom are unaffected by this option

Comment: This one is weird, when I decrease the size of my browser, I do not see any scrollbars. Can we make the chart responsive and dynamically adjust to the screen width and height?

Comment: Cytoscape.js is just a canvas, it doesn't react to the browser resize. You init it to some starting options (specific height, width,...) and you can provide css styles to the cy div, but after init the canvas does not change. As far as I know you can't change that, but I could be wrong. Try to stick to the original size anyways

Comment: Is there a way to add label at the top of the edge joining two nodes? I cannot find that in the documentation. If yes, what is the JSON for that edge

Comment: What do you mean by that, what would you define as a label on top of an edge?

Comment: Like text on the label saying from A to b or any text on the label like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdK5u.png